# Smoothing of scattered data on unstructured grid in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, smoothing

I have data on the grid which can be seen in the first scatter plot.

[image]

I visualized this data with `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter()` and set the scatter sizes and colors corresponding to the values so that it's more digestible, as you can see on the second figure. There are also some structures plotted, but that's not important.

[image: Data visualized]

I want to fit a 3D surface over this data with smoothing because simple interpolation is not the best for my purposes. Sometimes a couple of intersection lines specifically set their values to zeros, and you can see on the next figure what happens with linear (left) and cubic (right) interpolation when using `griddata()` from `scipy`. I tried with lower resolution grids as well but those gave the same results.

[image: linear and cubic interpolated data]

I want a smoothed fit which looks something like the linear interpolated left plot here, but without the obvious black lines where a line was set to zeros.

So then I tried the `SmoothBivariateSpline()` similarly to the example in the `scipy` documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/smoothing_splines.html#object-oriented-interface-smoothbivariatespline)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import SmoothBivariateSpline

...

smdata = []
factorlist = [0, 30, 200]
test_x = np.linspace(1, 2.2, 1200)
test_y = np.linspace(-1, 1.1, 2200)
extent = [test_x[0], test_x[-1], test_y[0], test_y[-1]]
train_x = points[:, 0].flatten()
train_y = points[:, 1].flatten()

for factor in factorlist:
    smth_func = SmoothBivariateSpline(train_x, train_y, values, s=factor)
    smdata.append(smth_func(test_x, test_y).T)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 6))

opts = dict(aspect='equal', extent=extent, vmin=0)
for k, factor in enumerate(factorlist):
    im = axes[k].imshow(smdata[k], **opts)
    axes[k].set_title('s={}'.format(factor))
    axes[k].scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], s=1, c="white")

plt.show()
```

Here `points` contain the x and y coordinates of the `values`. The resulting three different smoothing factor plots are not what I expected, and not what I want. Here they are with the instersections overlayed on top with white:[image]

So now I feel a little stuck. I would appreciate solutions in `numpy` and `scipy` if possible. If not really possible then I am open to other packages. Since I have access to the `values` and the `points` it could be also possible to try to interpolate the zeros to their neighbors or something similar, but I only want to do that as a last resort.